# How to capture full output of `git clone`?

Tags: git, shell, unix, pipe

When I run git clone like usual, I see this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/bensmithett/webpack-css-example
Cloning into 'webpack-css-example'...
remote: Counting objects: 179, done.
remote: Total 179 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 179
Receiving objects: 100% (179/179), 24.07 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (79/79), done.
Checking connectivity... done
```

However, when I try to redirect that to a file (or store it in a shell variable) I only see this:

```
Cloning into 'webpack-css-example'...
```

Here is what I tried:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/bensmithett/webpack-css-example 2>&1 | tee out.log
$ cat out.log
Cloning into 'sample-data'...
```

I tried it in Node.js as well, and it does the same thing:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const child = spawn('git clone https://github.com/bensmithett/webpack-css-example');
child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  console.log(String(data));
});
child.stderr.on('data', function(data){
  console.log(String(data));
});
// Cloning into 'webpack-css-example'...
```

Why is all the `remote:` etc. stuff not getting piped to either stdin/stderr? Is there any way to capture the output? If not, what is happening that makes it so the output is displayed in the terminal, yet it is not being passed through either stdout or stderr?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default Git will display the cloning progress only when the standard error stream is directed to a terminal. Since you're redirecting it to the pipe, the output stream is no longer attached to the terminal. So in order to capture the output, you need to add `--progress` parameter to force the progress status, e.g.

```
git clone --progress https://github.com/foo/bar 2> out.log
```

or, in order to store the output in a shell variable

```
out=$(git clone --progress https://github.com/foo/bar 2>&1)
```

See: `man git-clone`

> `--progress`
>
> Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default **when it is attached to a terminal**, unless `-q` is specified. This flag forces progress status even if the standard error stream is not directed to a terminal.

---

To force the terminal in any other way, you'll have to preload some library to force `isatty()` to return always true (see: `man isatty`). This function is used by git across the [source code](https://github.com/git/git/search?q=isatty&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: Is there a way to "pretend" it's a terminal that is running the command? That way the command can be run without any change to it's arguments. This is what I'm hoping for, git was just an example.

Comment: @LancePollard, not without extra tools such as `unbuffer`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How do you do it with that?

Comment: @LancePollard, ...also, these defaults exist for good reason. Full terminal output has things like color codes, cursor-positioning instructions, etc. You don't want those in machine-parsed logs. Usually, you don't want them in human-readable logs either.

Comment: `unbuffer git clone [...]`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is there a built in way to do this on Mac?

Comment: Pseudo-terminals (ptys) exist so that certain programs ("controlling programs" or "masters") can run other programs ("controlled") such that the controlled program *believes* it is talking interactively with a user, rather than talking with the controlling program.  The `script` command uses ptys, as do programs like `screen` and `tmux`, and there are libraries to use ptys from within programs written in C, Python, and so on.